# Remove and add actions in Wordpress using functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I have edited some plugin files in wordpress but this is bad form - it stand up to updates. I'd like to make the changes using functions.php but I can't get it to work correctly.

The basics are that I want to remove the following actions:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $this, 'my_account_memberships' ) );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', __CLASS__ . '::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
```

And in their place add the actions:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_accoun', array( $this, 'my_account_memberships' ) );

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', __CLASS__ . '::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
```

I have tried adding the following (for both sets) to my functions.php but to no avail...

```
remove_action ( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', __CLASS__ . '::get_my_subscriptions_template' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', __CLASS__ . '::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure that `__CLASS__` is not what you think it is here … Check the example under https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action#Example, and also pay attention to what it says about the priority.

Comment: `__CLASS__ .`  is part of the code directly from the plugin author

Comment: So what? It doesn’t mean it will have that same value inside of your `functions.php`.

Comment: So I should have `remove_action ( 'the_content', array ( get_my_subscriptions_template,  woocommerce_before_my_account)  )  `

Comment: Quote from the WP Codex above: _“**Important:** To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority arguments must match when the hook was added.”_ – would that be the case with those parameters …? No, not even close.

Comment: Put that code inside Wordpress `init` action

Comment: I am very close. @Danijel, I put it in an init action. Then I was schooled by a friend that __CLASS__ . and $this refer to the class that the action is taking place in. I didn't know this. I added the class names my code now places the subscription and membership info where I need it and it removes the subscriptions info from woocommerce_before_my_account. I just can't remove the memberships info. Heres what I have

Comment: 'add_action( 'init', 'move_subscription_info' );

function move_subscription_info() {
                remove_action ( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'WC_Subscriptions::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
    remove_action ( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( 'WC_Memberships_Frontend', 'my_account_memberships') );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', 'WC_Subscriptions::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', array('WC_Memberships_Frontend', 'my_account_memberships') );
}'

Comment: I figured it out. In case anyone else is struggling to achieve the same thing.  Here are the code snippets I used to move woocommerce My Subscriptions info and My Memberships info from the top of the woocommerce My Accounts page to a custom hook. I decided to place the hook that displays the subscription and membership and info at the bottom of the my accounts page (my-account.php) which is added to the child theme.

Comment: The hook is ` <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account' ); ?>`

Comment: and the code to be added to functions.php is `add_action( 'init', 'move_subscription_info' );

function move_subscription_info() {
                remove_action ( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'WC_Subscriptions::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', 'WC_Subscriptions::get_my_subscriptions_template' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', array('WC_Memberships_Frontend', 'my_account_memberships') );

Comment: if ( function_exists( 'wc_memberships' ) ) { 
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( wc_memberships()->frontend, 'my_account_memberships' ) );
   }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In case anyone else is struggling to achieve the same thing. Here are the code snippets I used to move woocommerce My Subscriptions info and My Memberships info from the top of the woocommerce My Accounts page to a custom hook. I decided to place the hook that displays the subscription and membership and info at the bottom of the my accounts page (my-account.php) which is added to the child theme.

The hook is:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account' );
```

and the code to be added to functions.php is

```
add_action( 'init', 'move_subscription_info' ); 
function move_subscription_info() {
remove_action ( 
'woocommerce_before_my_account','WC_Subscriptions::get_my_subscriptions_template' ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', 'WC_Subscriptions::get_my_subscriptions_template' ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_subscriptions_to_my_account', 
array('WC_Memberships_Frontend','my_account_memberships') ); 

if ( function_exists( 'wc_memberships' ) ) { 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( wc_memberships()->frontend, 'my_account_memberships' ) ); } }`
```